# How to start migrating a Java Swing application to JavaFX?

Tags: swing, javafx

Could any one experienced tell me better way to start?

I should start by the window, or by the buttons and labels? Or I need to do all at once? (would be terrible! I would like to do little parts and test each).

Answer (score 2):

Start by creating a [minimal, complete, and verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) of a particular design element abstracted from the Swing program. You may already have created (or at least studied) such an example is the course of creating the original. Recreate the same design element in JavaFX. This will allow you to proceed with confidence going forward and give you a ready source of isolated examples if you get stuck.

As a concrete example, [*Leveraging the observer pattern in JavaFX GUI design*](https://stackoverflow.com/q/31909941/230513) compares the Swing and JavaFX versions of a program that relies on the observer pattern.