# How to make stages with rounded corners or dropshadows?

Tags: javafx

I am just learning JavaFX, and I have found that a few years ago, some learned how to make nice (modal) stages with these styles. 
JavaFX Modal Confirm Dialog Box Example: https://gist.github.com/jewelsea/1887631/155d5e052b6ec7d0eaa6f825713f98f8e542152e
I recreated this OK, but some of the code is deprecated (builders).

So I wanted to ask if I can make a stage pop up that has rounded corners (or not), and maybe even dropshadows, using the currently supported API?  My application needs many popup stages, so I want to establish a nice style.

Comment: It's only the builders that are deprecated, isn't it? Just replace them with calls to constructors and set the properties in the usual way.

Comment: @James_D, I have not used builders before, and I'm trying to read the code.  It looks like the pane gets a style class of "modal-dialog-glass", and the hbox gets a style class of "modal-dialog-content", but also, there is a color of transparent at the end of the scene constructor?  I haven't figured out how to set the scene transparent.

Comment: @James_D, nm1  I didn't think I could do it, but I got it.  Thx.

Comment: @MarkMeyers: For reference, this [example](http://stackoverflow.com/a/31909942/230513) illustrates a few builder conversions.

Comment: @trashgod, Thanks.  For one, I think I will likely make a point of creating many `Observable` things in my application.  But I don't have a bunch of builder code to port, which is nice, and come to find out, learning through Google (like in my post here) is probably more likely to be a painful approach. These styles are so easy!  I have not previously experienced how they could have been so hard as to have created the above example to begin with, like, as if it were a good thing.

Answer (score 2):

I know I am a couple years late to this conversation, but I think it might be beneficial to share the workaround I found for the sake of whoever comes across this issue.

I managed to achieve the same by adding the following lines of code to my program:

```
Rectangle rect = new Rectangle(500,500);
rect.setArcHeight(60.0);
rect.setArcWidth(60.0);
primaryStage.initStyle(StageStyle.TRANSPARENT);
scene.setFill(Color.TRANSPARENT);
root.setClip(rect);
```

Source: https://apilevel.wordpress.com/2012/10/11/java-fx-stage-with-rounded-corners-with-background-image/

Answer (score 1):

I'll post the answer here for anyone who stumbles across the old examples as I did, using the CSS from the example.  I set the scene fill to transparent in Java, and not via CSS (which I do not know how to do, but that is fine).

```
       // initialize the stage
    primaryStage.setTitle("Modal Confirm Example");
    final WebView webView = new WebView(); webView.getEngine().load("http://docs.oracle.com/javafx/");
    primaryStage.setScene(new Scene(webView));
    primaryStage.show();

    // initialize the confirmation dialog
    final Stage util = new Stage(StageStyle.TRANSPARENT);
    util.initModality(Modality.APPLICATION_MODAL);
    util.initOwner(primaryStage);

    HBox hbox = new HBox();
    Pane pane = new Pane(hbox);
    Scene scene = new Scene(pane);
    Label label = new Label("Will you like this page?");
    Button yesButton = new Button("Yes");
    Button noButton = new Button("No");
    hbox.getChildren().addAll(label, yesButton, noButton);

    yesButton.setOnAction(ae -> {
        System.out.println("Liked: " + webView.getEngine().getTitle());
        primaryStage.getScene().getRoot().setEffect(null);
        util.close();
    });
    noButton.setOnAction(ae -> {
        System.out.println("Disliked: " + webView.getEngine().getTitle());
        primaryStage.getScene().getRoot().setEffect(null);
        util.close();
    });

    scene.setFill(Color.TRANSPARENT);
    scene.getStylesheets().add(Machine.class.getResource("modal-dialog.css").toExternalForm());
    pane.getStyleClass().add("modal-dialog-glass");
    hbox.getStyleClass().add("modal-dialog-content");

    util.setScene(scene);

    // show the confirmation dialog each time a new page is loaded.
    webView.getEngine().getLoadWorker().stateProperty().addListener(new ChangeListener<Worker.State>() {
      @Override public void changed(ObservableValue<? extends Worker.State> observableValue, Worker.State state, Worker.State newState) {
        if (newState.equals(Worker.State.SUCCEEDED)) {
          primaryStage.getScene().getRoot().setEffect(new BoxBlur());
          util.show();
          util.toFront();
        }
      }
    });
```

And this is from the example linked in the question... (plus a nonfunctional root class).

```
.root {
    -fx-background-color: transparent;
}

.modal-dialog-glass {
  -fx-effect: dropshadow(three-pass-box, derive(cadetblue, -20%), 10, 0, 4, 4); 
  -fx-background-color: derive(cadetblue, -20%); 
  -fx-background-insets: 12; 
  -fx-background-radius: 6;
}

.modal-dialog-content {
  -fx-padding: 20;
  -fx-spacing: 10;
  -fx-alignment: center;
  -fx-font-size: 20;
  -fx-background-color: linear-gradient(to bottom, derive(cadetblue, 20%), cadetblue);
  -fx-border-color: derive(cadetblue, -20%);
  -fx-border-width: 5;
  -fx-background-insets: 12;
  -fx-border-insets: 10;
  -fx-border-radius: 6;
  -fx-background-radius: 6;
}
```