# Where are the JavaFX 'Builder' classes?

Tags: java, javafx, netbeans

I've loaded the Netbeans sample program 'AdvancedMedia' and it is claiming it cannot find the following classes:

```
javafx.scene.control.ButtonBuilder
javafx.scene.control.LabelBuilder
javafx.scene.control.SliderBuilder
```

Looking in the *javafx-sdk-18.0.2/src/javafx.controls/javafx/scene/control* folder I can find the Button.java class but not ButtonBuilder. Likewise for the other two. Are these deprecated or am I looking in the wrong place?

My JavaFX libs are as follows:
[image: Netbeans Libs]

OS - Fedora 36

IDE - Netbeans 14

Java - zulu18.32.11-ca-fx-jdk18.0.2-linux_x64

JFX - openjfx18

Comment: Those classes were deprecated and then removed long ago.

Comment: Thanks. Looks like the Netbeans samples could do with a refresh!

Comment: *"Looks like the Netbeans samples could do with a refresh!"* - Submit an issue ...

Comment: @StephenC I've raised an issue at [#4528](https://github.com/apache/netbeans/issues/4528)

Comment: @KierranPurden Kudos for doing something about the situation. A lot of the NetBeans tutorials are out of date, and probably won't be fixed anytime soon because of resource issues, but formally logging the issue as a problem is a step in the right direction.

Answer (score 1):

As discussed in [*Proposal: Deprecate Builders*](https://mail.openjdk.org/pipermail/openjfx-dev/2013-March/006725.html), the builder classes have been deprecated for some time. The evolution of [scenebuilder](/questions/tagged/scenebuilder) has largely supplanted the typical use of such builder classes.

Nevertheless, many tutorials from that time remain useful. for example, [*JavaFX for Swing Developers*](https://docs.oracle.com/javafx/2/swing/jfxpub-swing.htm) offers guidance on migrating from Swing. In particular, this [example](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31909942/230513) illustrates eliminating the dependency from the JavaFX version of a popular Swing example.

Answer (score 1):

Those sample apps in Netbeans are built using `ANT`. I would suggest you finding the code and redoing the apps using a flow from https://openjfx.io/openjfx-docs/. I found an altered version of the sample program you are referring to.

Code From: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/media-tutorial/simpleplayer.htm

---

**Main**

```
/*
 * Copyright (c) 2012, 2014 Oracle and/or its affiliates.
 * All rights reserved. Use is subject to license terms.
 *
 * This file is available and licensed under the following license:
 *
 * Redistribution and use in source and binary forms, with or without
 * modification, are permitted provided that the following conditions
 * are met:
 *
 *  - Redistributions of source code must retain the above copyright
 *    notice, this list of conditions and the following disclaimer.
 *  - Redistributions in binary form must reproduce the above copyright
 *    notice, this list of conditions and the following disclaimer in
 *    the documentation and/or other materials provided with the distribution.
 *  - Neither the name of Oracle nor the names of its
 *    contributors may be used to endorse or promote products derived
 *    from this software without specific prior written permission.
 *
 * THIS SOFTWARE IS PROVIDED BY THE COPYRIGHT HOLDERS AND CONTRIBUTORS
 * "AS IS" AND ANY EXPRESS OR IMPLIED WARRANTIES, INCLUDING, BUT NOT
 * LIMITED TO, THE IMPLIED WARRANTIES OF MERCHANTABILITY AND FITNESS FOR
 * A PARTICULAR PURPOSE ARE DISCLAIMED. IN NO EVENT SHALL THE COPYRIGHT
 * OWNER OR CONTRIBUTORS BE LIABLE FOR ANY DIRECT, INDIRECT, INCIDENTAL,
 * SPECIAL, EXEMPLARY, OR CONSEQUENTIAL DAMAGES (INCLUDING, BUT NOT
 * LIMITED TO, PROCUREMENT OF SUBSTITUTE GOODS OR SERVICES; LOSS OF USE,
 * DATA, OR PROFITS; OR BUSINESS INTERRUPTION) HOWEVER CAUSED AND ON ANY
 * THEORY OF LIABILITY, WHETHER IN CONTRACT, STRICT LIABILITY, OR TORT
 * (INCLUDING NEGLIGENCE OR OTHERWISE) ARISING IN ANY WAY OUT OF THE USE
 * OF THIS SOFTWARE, EVEN IF ADVISED OF THE POSSIBILITY OF SUCH DAMAGE.
 */

import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.scene.Group;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.media.Media;
import javafx.scene.media.MediaPlayer;
import javafx.stage.Stage;

public class EmbeddedMediaPlayer extends Application {

    private static final String MEDIA_URL =
            "https://ia801604.us.archive.org/31/items/vhsvault_Game_Genie_advert/Game_Genie_advert-xgzfuyeOrbg.mp4";

    
    @Override
    public void start(Stage primaryStage) {
        
        primaryStage.setTitle("Embedded Media Player");
        Group root = new Group();
        Scene scene = new Scene(root, 540, 241);

        // create media player
        Media media = new Media (MEDIA_URL);
        MediaPlayer mediaPlayer = new MediaPlayer(media);
        mediaPlayer.setAutoPlay(true);
        
        MediaControl mediaControl = new MediaControl(mediaPlayer);
        scene.setRoot(mediaControl);

        primaryStage.setScene(scene);
        primaryStage.sizeToScene();
        primaryStage.show();
        
    }

    /**
     * The main() method is ignored in correctly deployed JavaFX application.
     * main() serves only as fallback in case the application can not be
     * launched through deployment artifacts, e.g., in IDEs with limited FX
     * support. NetBeans ignores main().
     *
     * @param args the command line arguments
     */
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch(args);
    }
}
```

---

**EmbeddedMediaPlayer**

```
/*
 * Copyright (c) 2012, 2014 Oracle and/or its affiliates.
 * All rights reserved. Use is subject to license terms.
 *
 * This file is available and licensed under the following license:
 *
 * Redistribution and use in source and binary forms, with or without
 * modification, are permitted provided that the following conditions
 * are met:
 *
 *  - Redistributions of source code must retain the above copyright
 *    notice, this list of conditions and the following disclaimer.
 *  - Redistributions in binary form must reproduce the above copyright
 *    notice, this list of conditions and the following disclaimer in
 *    the documentation and/or other materials provided with the distribution.
 *  - Neither the name of Oracle nor the names of its
 *    contributors may be used to endorse or promote products derived
 *    from this software without specific prior written permission.
 *
 * THIS SOFTWARE IS PROVIDED BY THE COPYRIGHT HOLDERS AND CONTRIBUTORS
 * "AS IS" AND ANY EXPRESS OR IMPLIED WARRANTIES, INCLUDING, BUT NOT
 * LIMITED TO, THE IMPLIED WARRANTIES OF MERCHANTABILITY AND FITNESS FOR
 * A PARTICULAR PURPOSE ARE DISCLAIMED. IN NO EVENT SHALL THE COPYRIGHT
 * OWNER OR CONTRIBUTORS BE LIABLE FOR ANY DIRECT, INDIRECT, INCIDENTAL,
 * SPECIAL, EXEMPLARY, OR CONSEQUENTIAL DAMAGES (INCLUDING, BUT NOT
 * LIMITED TO, PROCUREMENT OF SUBSTITUTE GOODS OR SERVICES; LOSS OF USE,
 * DATA, OR PROFITS; OR BUSINESS INTERRUPTION) HOWEVER CAUSED AND ON ANY
 * THEORY OF LIABILITY, WHETHER IN CONTRACT, STRICT LIABILITY, OR TORT
 * (INCLUDING NEGLIGENCE OR OTHERWISE) ARISING IN ANY WAY OUT OF THE USE
 * OF THIS SOFTWARE, EVEN IF ADVISED OF THE POSSIBILITY OF SUCH DAMAGE.
 */

import javafx.application.Platform;
import javafx.beans.InvalidationListener;
import javafx.beans.Observable;
import javafx.event.ActionEvent;
import javafx.event.EventHandler;
import javafx.scene.layout.Priority;
import javafx.scene.layout.Region;
import javafx.geometry.Insets;
import javafx.geometry.Pos;
import javafx.scene.control.Button;
import javafx.scene.control.Label;
import javafx.scene.control.Slider;
import javafx.scene.layout.BorderPane;
import javafx.scene.layout.HBox;
import javafx.scene.layout.Pane;
import javafx.scene.media.MediaPlayer;
import javafx.scene.media.MediaPlayer.Status;
import javafx.scene.media.MediaView;
import javafx.util.Duration;

public class MediaControl extends BorderPane {

    private MediaPlayer mp;
    private MediaView mediaView;
    private final boolean repeat = false;
    private boolean stopRequested = false;
    private boolean atEndOfMedia = false;
    private Duration duration;
    private Slider timeSlider;
    private Label playTime;
    private Slider volumeSlider;
    private HBox mediaBar;

    public MediaControl(final MediaPlayer mp) {
        this.mp = mp;
        setStyle("-fx-background-color: #bfc2c7;");
        mediaView = new MediaView(mp);
        Pane mvPane = new Pane() {
        };
        mvPane.getChildren().add(mediaView);
        mvPane.setStyle("-fx-background-color: black;");
        setCenter(mvPane);

        mediaBar = new HBox();
        mediaBar.setAlignment(Pos.CENTER);
        mediaBar.setPadding(new Insets(5, 10, 5, 10));
        BorderPane.setAlignment(mediaBar, Pos.CENTER);

        final Button playButton = new Button(">");

        playButton.setOnAction(new EventHandler<ActionEvent>() {
            public void handle(ActionEvent e) {
                Status status = mp.getStatus();

                if (status == Status.UNKNOWN || status == Status.HALTED) {
                    // don't do anything in these states
                    return;
                }

                if (status == Status.PAUSED
                        || status == Status.READY
                        || status == Status.STOPPED) {
                    // rewind the movie if we're sitting at the end
                    if (atEndOfMedia) {
                        mp.seek(mp.getStartTime());
                        atEndOfMedia = false;
                    }
                    mp.play();
                } else {
                    mp.pause();
                }
            }
        });
        mp.currentTimeProperty().addListener(new InvalidationListener() {
            public void invalidated(Observable ov) {
                updateValues();
            }
        });

        mp.setOnPlaying(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                if (stopRequested) {
                    mp.pause();
                    stopRequested = false;
                } else {
                    playButton.setText("||");
                }
            }
        });

        mp.setOnPaused(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                System.out.println("onPaused");
                playButton.setText(">");
            }
        });

        mp.setOnReady(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                duration = mp.getMedia().getDuration();
                updateValues();
            }
        });

        mp.setCycleCount(repeat ? MediaPlayer.INDEFINITE : 1);
        mp.setOnEndOfMedia(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                if (!repeat) {
                    playButton.setText(">");
                    stopRequested = true;
                    atEndOfMedia = true;
                }
            }
        });

        mediaBar.getChildren().add(playButton);
        // Add spacer
        Label spacer = new Label("   ");
        mediaBar.getChildren().add(spacer);

        // Add Time label
        Label timeLabel = new Label("Time: ");
        mediaBar.getChildren().add(timeLabel);

        // Add time slider
        timeSlider = new Slider();
        HBox.setHgrow(timeSlider, Priority.ALWAYS);
        timeSlider.setMinWidth(50);
        timeSlider.setMaxWidth(Double.MAX_VALUE);
        timeSlider.valueProperty().addListener(new InvalidationListener() {
            public void invalidated(Observable ov) {
                if (timeSlider.isValueChanging()) {
                    // multiply duration by percentage calculated by slider position
                    mp.seek(duration.multiply(timeSlider.getValue() / 100.0));
                }
            }
        });
        mediaBar.getChildren().add(timeSlider);

        // Add Play label
        playTime = new Label();
        playTime.setPrefWidth(130);
        playTime.setMinWidth(50);
        mediaBar.getChildren().add(playTime);

        // Add the volume label
        Label volumeLabel = new Label("Vol: ");
        mediaBar.getChildren().add(volumeLabel);

        // Add Volume slider
        volumeSlider = new Slider();
        volumeSlider.setPrefWidth(70);
        volumeSlider.setMaxWidth(Region.USE_PREF_SIZE);
        volumeSlider.setMinWidth(30);
        volumeSlider.valueProperty().addListener(new InvalidationListener() {
            public void invalidated(Observable ov) {
                if (volumeSlider.isValueChanging()) {
                    mp.setVolume(volumeSlider.getValue() / 100.0);
                }
            }
        });
        mediaBar.getChildren().add(volumeSlider);

        setBottom(mediaBar);
    }

    protected void updateValues() {
        if (playTime != null && timeSlider != null && volumeSlider != null) {
            Platform.runLater(new Runnable() {
                public void run() {
                    Duration currentTime = mp.getCurrentTime();
                    playTime.setText(formatTime(currentTime, duration));
                    timeSlider.setDisable(duration.isUnknown());
                    if (!timeSlider.isDisabled()
                            && duration.greaterThan(Duration.ZERO)
                            && !timeSlider.isValueChanging()) {
                        timeSlider.setValue(currentTime.divide(duration).toMillis()
                                * 100.0);
                    }
                    if (!volumeSlider.isValueChanging()) {
                        volumeSlider.setValue((int) Math.round(mp.getVolume()
                                * 100));
                    }
                }
            });
        }
    }

    private static String formatTime(Duration elapsed, Duration duration) {
        int intElapsed = (int) Math.floor(elapsed.toSeconds());
        int elapsedHours = intElapsed / (60 * 60);
        if (elapsedHours > 0) {
            intElapsed -= elapsedHours * 60 * 60;
        }
        int elapsedMinutes = intElapsed / 60;
        int elapsedSeconds = intElapsed - elapsedHours * 60 * 60
                - elapsedMinutes * 60;

        if (duration.greaterThan(Duration.ZERO)) {
            int intDuration = (int) Math.floor(duration.toSeconds());
            int durationHours = intDuration / (60 * 60);
            if (durationHours > 0) {
                intDuration -= durationHours * 60 * 60;
            }
            int durationMinutes = intDuration / 60;
            int durationSeconds = intDuration - durationHours * 60 * 60
                    - durationMinutes * 60;
            if (durationHours > 0) {
                return String.format("%d:%02d:%02d/%d:%02d:%02d",
                        elapsedHours, elapsedMinutes, elapsedSeconds,
                        durationHours, durationMinutes, durationSeconds);
            } else {
                return String.format("%02d:%02d/%02d:%02d",
                        elapsedMinutes, elapsedSeconds, durationMinutes,
                        durationSeconds);
            }
        } else {
            if (elapsedHours > 0) {
                return String.format("%d:%02d:%02d", elapsedHours,
                        elapsedMinutes, elapsedSeconds);
            } else {
                return String.format("%02d:%02d", elapsedMinutes,
                        elapsedSeconds);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

---

**Module-Info**

```
requires javafx.controls;
requires javafx.media;
    
exports com.mycompany.mavenproject21;
```

---

**Output**

[image]